# How to make jQuery work in admin area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

I have included Twitter Bootstrap with in my theme options page in WordPress to help style the theme options page. Before, when I was de-registering jQuery and adding my own version, all code was working with the `$`, because I didn't have to worry about WordPress's way of always having a `jQuery` appended to everything, I could just use `$` and be done with it.

Unfortunately, you are not supposed to de-register jQuery, even if it's only done on your own admin pages.

So I looked around for some ways to still use the `$` in jQuery and wrote this:

```
(function($){   
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.posts').click(function(){
            if ($(this).attr("id") == "list"){
                $('.sectionLists').show();
            } else {
                $('.sectionLists').hide();
            }
        });
});
})(jQuery);
```

There are no console errors - in my code, yet none of my Twitter Bootstrap Javascript dependent functions are working, such as Popovers, Tabs or anything else of that nature, and the above code doesn't even work.

However if I paste it into Chrome console and hit enter, it works as it should.

Whats going on?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably trying to call jQuery before it is loaded - that's why it doesn't work in page but does in the console.

Are you adding the jQuery dependency like below and as shown in the Codex at [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)?

```
function iamb_inc_bootstrap() {

    wp_register_script(
        'js_bootstrap',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js',
        array('jquery'),
        '20130219',
        true
    );

    wp_enqueue_script('js_bootstrap');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'iamb_inc_bootstrap');
```

Answer (score 1):

Disregarding the [correct way](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) of enqueueing scripts and stylesheets, this is how I always do it:

```
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'wpse_46677_change_menu_item' );

function wpse_46677_change_menu_item()
{
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
                $( "#menu-appearance" )
                    .find( "li:contains( 'Header' )" )
                    .html( '<a href="themes.php?page=custom-header">My Text</a> ');
            });     
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

<sub>From [this WordPress Answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/67972/12615).</sub>